# Add callback to dynamically created ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating an ActiveRecord class dynamically, and have code along the lines of the following:

```
new_klass = Class.new ActiveRecord::Base do
  cattr_accessor :model_name
  self.abstract_class = false
  self.table_name = "foo"

  # do more stuff...


end

Object.const_set "Foo", new_klass
```

How can I add a callback to this class, for example, a **before_save** callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see your problem you don't need anything since you are in the class scope, just call the callback methods you want to register ...

Below i've added a validation callback to prevent instance validation :

```
new_klass = Class.new ActiveRecord::Base do
  cattr_accessor :model_name
  self.abstract_class = false
  self.table_name = "items"
  validate do 
    errors.add :base, "not good"
  end
end

> instance = new_klass.new
> instance.valid?
=> false
> instance.errors.full_messages
=> ["not good"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try including a concern to your dynamic class, and then handle it there.

```
new_klass = Class.new ActiveRecord::Base do
  #...
  include MyConcern
  #...
end

# app/models/concerns/my_concern.rb
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save ...
  end
end
```